# Mysql resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: mysql

I'm seeing a few of these errors during high load times:

```
mysql_connect() [<a
href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: [2002] Resource
temporarily unavailable (trying to connect via
unix:///var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)
```

From what I can tell the mysql server isn't hitting its max connections limit, but there's something else stopping it from serving the query. What other limits would MySQL be hitting?

I'm running RHEL 6.2 64bit with MySQL 5.5.21

Comment: It may be a bug in the mysql server? It could also be the result of how the mysql server is handling requests having issues at high volumes, such as when requests are almost simultaneous according to some clock measure.

Comment: are you reusing connections or just opening new ones? without some code it's hard to make an educated guess at what's wrong.

Comment: Connections aren't persistent across php requests. I read somewhere about mysql running out of file descriptors, but I'm unsure how to check that.

Comment: can you check mysql log, may be that can give a hint to problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still haven't found which limits it was hitting, but I did manage to work around the problem. There was a problem with our session table (in vbulletin) which uses the MEMORY engine. The indexes for this table were HASH and thus when vbulletin purged this table once an hour it would lock the table just long enough to hold up other queries and push mysql to the limit of its resources.

By changing the indexes to BTREE this allowed MySQL to delete the rows from the session table a lot quicker and avoid any limits there were reached previously. The errors only started when we upgraded our master db server to MySQL 5.5, so I'm guessing MEMORY tables are handled differently in the latest release.

See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/02/01/performance-gotcha-of-mysql-memory-tables/ for information on speed increases from using BTREE indexes over HASH For MEMORY.

Answer (score 27):

Let's assume your system is currently Unix-based (as given in your problem statement). If this is correct, here's the set of issues you may be running into:

1. You've run out of [memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_memory) available to MySQL.

   This is the most likely problem you're facing. Each connection in MySQL's connection pool requires memory to function, and if this resource is exhausted, no further connections can be made. Of course, the memory footprints and maximum packet sizes of various operations can be tuned in [your equivalent to `my.cnf`](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html) if you discover this to be an issue.

   [Here's an additional thread that can help there](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/05/17/mysql-server-memory-usage/), but you may also consider using simpler profiling tools like `top` to get a good ballpark estimate of what's going on.
2. You've run out of [file descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) available to your MySQL user account.

   Another common issue: if you're trying to service requests that require file IO above the 1,024 boundary (by default), you will run into cases where the operation simply fails. This is because most systems specify a soft and hard limit on the number of open file descriptors each user can have available at one time, and walking over this threshold can cause problems.

   This will usually have a series of glaringly obvious signs expressed in your log files. Check `/var/log/messages` and your comparable directories (for example, `/var/log/mysql` to see if you can find anything interesting.
3. You've run into a [livelock or deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) scenario where your thread is unsatisfiable.

   Corollary to memory and file descriptor exhaustion, threads can time out if you've overstepped the computational load your system is capable of handling. It won't throw this error message, but this is something to watch out for in the future.
4. Your system is running out of PIDs available to [`fork`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29).

   Another common scenario: `fork` only has so many PIDs available for its use at any given time. If your system is simply [overforked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb), it will cease to be able to service requests.

   The easiest check for this is to see if any other services can connect through to the machine. For example, trying to SSH into the box and discovering that you cannot is a big clue.
5. An upstream proxy or connection manager has run out of resources and ceased servicing requests.

   If you have any service layer between your client and MySQL, it bears inspecting to see if it has crashed, hung, or otherwise become unstable. The advice above applies.
6. Your port mapper has exhausted itself [after 65,536 connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29).

   Unlikely, but again, a possible exhaustion case. Checking the trivial service connection as above is, ehm, also the best port of call here.

In short: **this is a resource exhaustion scenario, inclusive of the server simply being "down".** You're going to have to profile your system further to see what you're blocking on. All the error message gives us in this case is the fact the resource is unavailable to the client -- we'd need to see more information about the *server* to determine a more adequate remedy.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, but could you point me in the right place to test for each of these? I doubt I've run out of memory (12GB of memory in each one of our servers), but I'd need to look into the others.

Comment: @Noodles Will do. I need to handle some things at my end first, but I'll get back to pulling a bit more documentation into my answer hopefully within the next hour or so. :)

Comment: My answer has been updated. My time estimate was a little off, but that should be enough to help with the troubleshooting. If you need more cogent, specific advice, please let me know. I'll be happy to make myself available via SO chat.

Comment: Hmmm... I ran through your suggestions and can't see any obvious problems. I started looking into file descriptor limits, but "cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max" shows 1200877 and "lsof -u mysql | wc -l" shows 2862, so it's nowhere near the limit. There's no layers between Apache and MySQL (on the same box), using Xymon it doesn't look like memory is topping out. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Noodles In that case, I'd recommend giving [`mysqlslap`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html) a try and seeing what falls out of your log files. Here's [an additional page of info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/custom-benchmarks.html) that might help. If that doesn't work, connection-level troubleshooting is going to be necessary, because it may not be a problem with your MySQL server.

Comment: Have created a chatroom if your offer to chat is still available.

Answer (score 2):

Geez, this could be so many things.  It could be that the socket buffer space is exhausted.  It could be that `mysql` is not accepting connections as fast as they are coming in and the backlog limit is reached (though I'd expect that to give you a "Connection Refused" error, I don't know for sure that's what you'll get for a Unix domain socket).  It could be any of the things @MrGomez pointed out.

Since you are running Apache and MySQL on the same server and this is a problem under high load, it could well be that Apache is starving the system of some resource and you're just not seeing (noticing?) the dropped/failed incoming connections/requests in your logs.

Are you using connection pooling?  If not, I'd start there.

I'd also look for errors in the Apache logs and syslog around the same time as the mysql_connect error and see what else turns up.  I'd especially recommend getting MySQL moved over to its own separate dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working with `JSON` data types with `PDO` (PHP Driver).
I was using `fetch` to retrieve one item but forgot to add `LIMIT 1` to the query. Adding it solved the problem.