# Random/intermittent error "mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory" with Wordpress multisite install on MS Azure

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure

This error keeps popping once in few days and gets resolved upon restarting the server.

I am looking for the root cause and a permanent solution for this. I have looked around for solutions but couldn't find any. Following are some of the posts I checked -

a) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071241/sqlstatehy000-2002-resource-temporarily-unavailable-mysql-innodb-and-pdo)

b) [This too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131615/mysql-resource-temporarily-unavailable/10166116#10166116)

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: what is your database tier? maybe the database isn't available all the time!